# App work's fine when device connected to Xcode, but fails when installing ipa, on specific location

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, swift, crash

i am using Xcode 6.2(beta), facing issue i.e My app work's fine when device connected to Xcode, but fails when installing ipa, on specific location, when the app crash on specific location, i am able to get the crash location and line number using crash log (when app is installed and it get crash), so debugging on installed app is quite tedious, and why the app is running smooth when device connected to Xcode. please help or any way to make app running consistently on both way while connected to Xcode and on installing ipa.
**Also i am coding in Swift 1.2**

Comment: at least post the crash log

Comment: Below some piece of Crash log ::

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib             0x0048ae18 0x2f8000 + 1650200


1   HealthWatchiOS                 0x000f09d0 HealthWatchiOS.McdSettingsViewController.setPreTimeToText (HealthWatchiOS.McdSettingsViewController)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () (McdSettingsViewController.swift:236)

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your project document file not set the target.Please check all project file target.

Comment: Can you explain it, how to perform the task, the way your are saying